# i am unable to inspect wkWebView of an ios app in appium inspector , it highlights full screen as a single locator

Tags: wkwebview, appium-ios, appium-inspector

[image: there is No single locator selected]

tried with appium inspector for an ios app

Answer (score 1):

The screen that you're inspecting is a web view. You can directly automate this by switching the driver context and you may try inspecting after connecting your device using following way.

1. Android -> chrome://inspect/#devices
2. Safari -> develop menu

For switching driver context:

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
  if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW"))
      DriverFactory.driver.context(contextName);
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers